# How to describe the set field in Django

Tags: django-models, set

I have an article object, and like to assign it some tags (I have up to 30 predefined categories)
so I need an ordered set of attributes in ArticleModel.

I tried to create several ForeignKeys to the TagsTable, but in this case user can set same tag more than once.

Is there any standard approach to store a set field in Django ORM?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ForeignKey, use ManyToManyField in your ArticleModel.

Comment: I don't want to have additional table to query. I'd prefer to store this field as comma-separated string or something like this.

AFAIK database engines has sets as basic types